# Insert values from several views

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have three views, reembolsos_v, tarjetas_v and no_pagos_v. I want to insert values of these views into a table named acciones.

The columns of reembolsos_v are the following:

```
hora             reembolsos
00               2
02               13
03               39
```

The columns of tarjetas_v are the following:

```
hora             tarjetas
00               6
02               12
03               42
```

The columns of no_pagos_v are the following:

```
hora             no_pagos
00               3
01               2
03               11
```

The table acciones has the following columns:

```
hora             pagocr           pago          no_pago
```

I want to insert values of columns of the three views into table acciones in the following way: in the column hora of the table acciones insert values of columns horas of the views, in the column pagocr I want to insert values of column reembolsos, in the column pago I want to insert values of column tarjetas and in the column no_pago of the table acciones I want to insert values of column no_pagos.

I tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO acciones(hora,pagocr,pago,no_pago) 
SELECT r.hora, r.reembolsos, t.tarjetas, n.no_pagos FROM 
reembolsos_v AS r, tarjetas_v AS t, no_pagos_v AS n
```

The result of this query is something like this:

```
hora      pagocr      pago      no_pago
00        2           6         3 
00        2           6         2
00        2           6         11
```

It is not the right result. The correct result is the following:

```
hora      pagocr      pago      no_pago
00        2           6         3
02        13          12        null
03        49          32        11
```

How can I get the right results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query as shown in the question performs a catersian product i.e. every row in one table gets joined with all the other rows in the other table(s). However a `full join` is needed in this case.

```
SELECT COALESCE(r.hora,t.hora,n.hora) as hora,r.reembolsos,t.tarjetas,n.no_pagos 
FROM reembolsos_v r 
FULL JOIN tarjetas_v t on t.hora = r.hora
FULL JOIN no_pagos_v n on n.hora = t.hora
```

Comment: The complete solution is the following query: INSERT INTO acciones(hora,pagocr,pago,no_pago)
SELECT COALESCE(r.hora,t.hora,n.hora) as hora,r.reembolsos,t.tarjetas,n.no_pagos 
FROM axmugbcn18.reembolsos_v r 
FULL JOIN axmugbcn18.tarjetas_v t on t.hora = r.hora
FULL JOIN axmugbcn18.no_pagos_v n on n.hora = t.hora